# Breaking Sky and the Main Character

Tags: breaking-sky

*Breaking Sky* is a new book that came out in March 2015. It is really good bit a little hard to understand. First, how did China become so great and the U.S. fall so fast? Second, does Pippin really die or was that a partial figment of Chase's imagination?

Comment: This is really two separate questions, you should break it apart. A little more detail would also be good.

Comment: Breaking sky is a new book so that is good advice.

Comment: Who's the author?

Comment: Cori McCarthy is the author